# Run multiple SSH sessions in parallel

Tags: bash, shell, expect

I have a script that helps me update the IOS of my Cisco devices when ever I need to. It works fine and I have no issues with the script itself other then the fact that it only does one device at a time.

Is there something that I can research to make the script run asymmetrically so it can do multiple sessions at one time?

The script consists of an expect script which is setup like so:

```
set timeout 6
set hostname [lindex argv $0]
set password [lindex argv $1]

spawn ssh $hostname

expect "TACACS*:"
send "$password\r"

expect "#"
send "term length 0\r"
< other similar commands >

interact
```

The main bash script works as follows:

```
IP=$(cat ./iphosts)

read -p "Please enter your TACACS Password:" password

for i in $IP
do
     expect 01.exp $i $password | tee -a bulk.log
done

interact
```

Both the expect and .sh script have a little bit more to each but those usually post script completion tasks like reporting or additional commands.

Thank you for any information that you can provide on this!

Comment: Doesn't have anything to do with your question: add `-s` to the shell `read` command so the password is not visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `xargs` tool to start a number of processes in parallel.  For example:

```
#!/bin/sh

read -p "Please enter your TACACS Password:" password
xargs -IADDRESS -P4 expect 01.exp ADDRESS $password < ./iphosts
```

This uses the `-P` argument to `xargs` to run up to 4 processes at a time. You could scale up the argument to `-P` to run more processes in parallel.

But there's a problem here: you're calling `interact` in your expect script, which suggests that the script is expecting (possibly requires) interactive input from you when it is running.  If this is the case, the solution presented here won't work.  You would need to rewrite your `expect` script so that it does not require any user interaction.

You may also want to investigate a tool like [Ansible](http://ansible.com/) which (a) does this sort of parallel execution by default and (b) has explicit support [for configuring a variety of network devices](https://www.ansible.com/integrations/networks).

Comment: Thank you kindly sir! I will definitely look into this! This will help me I'm sure!